# Error in nparcomp::mctp: "Error in checkmvArgs ... not specified or contains NA", although data contains no NA

Tags: r, comparison

I have the following problem occurring with nparcomp::mctp(). 
I typed in the following command and yielded the following error message which I could not find a solution for.

Data:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Values = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 9, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 4, 1, 0, 2, 2, 8, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 8, 7, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 10, 0, 0, 5, 4, 2, 6, 21, 5, 14, 3, 24, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 0, 9, 3, 2, 0, 4, 7, 3, 20, 2, 3, 1, 7, 5, 5, 22, 40, 23, 7, 45, 38, 11, 9, 7, 3, 32, 5, 1, 4, 6, 5, 0, 5, 4, 2),
  Weeks  = sort(rep(1:12, 10)),
  Rep    = rep(1:10, 12)
  )
```

Used function command:

```
npar.1 <- nparcomp::mctp(Values ~ Weeks, 
           data = data, 
           type = "Tukey", alternative = "two.sided", 
           asy.method = "normal")
```

Error message:

```
Error in checkmvArgs(lower = lower, upper = upper, mean = delta, corr = corr,  : ‘lower’ not specified or contains NA 
In addition: Warning message: 
In cov2cor(CV) : diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful
```

I tried the other asymptotic approximation methods as well, however, no success.

So, I found this instruction ([dataset limitation in R package "nparcomp"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047659/dataset-limitation-in-r-package-nparcomp)) and followed the instruction given modifying the source code. I installed the modified source as followed:

```
install.package("path", repo = NULL, type = "source")
```

Unfortunately, without any changed result.

Please, does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem or had similar difficulties?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your data correctly, I believe you are seeing this because there there are some Weeks which, no matter what their Rep is, only have Values of zero. Thus, when the Tukey test tries to find a grand mean with which to make comparisons, it struggles.

Without knowing your data, I don't know if it is appropriate to remove Weeks 1 and 2, but it looks like that solves the error.